# System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute in .NET Core

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, system.reflection

I'm trying to convert the following method (which works fine in .NET Framework 4.6.2) to .NET Core 1.1.

```
public static TAttribute GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(MemberInfo member) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var attr = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(TAttribute));
    if (attr is TAttribute)
       return attr;
    else
       return null;
}
```

This code is giving me the error

> Attribute does not contain a definition for GetCustomAttribute.

Any idea what the .NET Core equivalent of this should be?

P.S. I tried the following but it seems to throw an exception. Not sure what the exception is because it just stops the app all together. I tried putting the code in a `try catch` block but still it just stops running so I couldn't capture the exception.

```
public static TAttribute GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(MemberInfo member) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
   var attr = GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(member);
   if (attr is TAttribute)
      return attr;
   else
      return null;
}
```

Comment: Your `PS` code is hitting a StackOverflowException since in the first line it's just calling itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add a package reference to `System.Reflection.Extensions` or `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`, then `MemberInfo` gets a lot of extension methods like `GetCustomAttribute<T>()`, `GetCustomAttributes<T>()`, `GetCustomAttributes()`, etc. You use those instead. The extension methods are declared in `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions`, so you'll need a `using` directive of:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

In your case, `member.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>()` should do everything you need.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `GetCustomAttribute` method:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

typeof(<class name>).GetTypeInfo()
      .GetProperty(<property name>).GetCustomAttribute<YourAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 3):

As found on `.Net Framework Core official GitHub` page, use the following

```
type.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes()
```

[github link for more information](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2222)